# How to pass/inject Interface in Invocable class

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, coravel

I am working on worker service using [Coraval](https://docs.coravel.net/) library, following [this](https://dev.to/jamesmh/building-a-net-core-scheduled-job-worker-service-376h) article. From `Program.cs` class I want to pass `Invocable` class and `Interface` but not sure how to pass `Interface`. This is my `Program.cs` class code

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler => {
            // Remind schedular to repeat the same job in every five-second   
            scheduler
                .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
                .EveryTenSeconds();
        });
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureServices(services =>
          {
            services.AddScheduler();
            // register job with container  
            services.AddTransient<ReprocessInvocable>();
          });
}
```

`Invocable` class

```
public class ReprocessInvocable : IInvocable
{
    IForceReprocess _forceReprocess;


    public ReprocessInvocable(IForceReprocess forceReprocess)
    {
        _forceReprocess = forceReprocess;
    }

   public async Task Invoke()
    {
        _forceReprocess.GetFailedProduct();
        Console.WriteLine("Works fine... my first schedule job.......!!!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        //return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

May be I need pass `interface` here `services.AddTransient<ReprocessInvocable>();`

Comment: Your `ReprocessInvocable` expects to be injected with an `IForceReprocess`. You need to also register a mapping for this, otherwise the DI framework cannot create an instance of `ReprocessInvocable`.

Comment: @Fildor - How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know. Do you have something that implements that Interface? Let's say a class named `ForceProc` does. Then you'd insert another line before services.AddTransient<ReprocessInvocable>() like services.AddTransient<IForceReprocess, ForceProc>()

Comment: This line  `services.AddScoped<IForceReprocess,GetProeductsToPush>();` not showing any error but not invoking any class and method